# flutter Typehead shows error 'A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_keyboard_visibility'.'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

when i try to use flutter_typehead package i get this error:

[image]
flutter doctor:

[image]

pubspec.yaml:

[image]

Comment: Didn't find ```flutter_keyboard_visibility``` in your ```pubspec.yml``` file so can you try to clean project and rerun . Sometime it happens some caches issues

Comment: i did flutter clean and then pub get but nothing same error also i tried to add it manualy to the pubspec file -> flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.4.3 but i still get same error

Comment: not flutter clean . open android folder of project in android studio . Click on Build tab and click ```clean project```

Comment: i did clean project too and have the same issue

Comment: i found a solution after doing 3 steps:

1/ deleting the package flutter_keyboard_visibility manually(you can find it in src file)

2/ removing the pubspec.lock file from my project

3/ running pub get (you don't need flutter_keyboard_visibility to be in your pubspec.yaml file since flutter_typehead will install it automatically)

Comment: You should be using the built-in Autocomplete instead of the third-party flutter_typeahead (misnamed, gah) now.